# How to run Apache server from Docker without mapping to a location?

Tags: linux, apache, docker, devops

Docker Image: has apache; has an HTML file in the apache root.

How can I access that file form the browser? (when I run the image)

I tried:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 myimage/myimage
```

but when I do `docker ps` I see the port as `0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp` but I get HTTP ERROR 500 when opening `0.0.0.0:8080` or `localhost:8080`.

Comment: is `myimage` created properly?

Comment: Can you edit and include your Dockerfile for myimage/myimage? Likely the problem is somewhere in there, as the `docker run` command you posted seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login in to docker container

```
docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash
```

and start apache server if its not started.

```
 service apache2 restart
```

Then from browser access using : http://localhost:8080

Comment: If you're seeing a 500 error, that's Apache responding, so the web server is already running.

Comment: ohhh yes i seen 0.0.0.0:8080 this part and confused erro-code , then maybe its file permission issue,
chown www-data:www-data html

Comment: seems as if apache is not showing php. I added a html file and it's ok. (php7 is installed in the container)